# Using ActionMailer default_options "from" in RoR application configuration.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, redmine

I'm deploying Redmine 4.1.1 (a RoR application) on my company server with Ruby 2.4.5 but I'm not able to use SMTP functions.

I have to use ActionMailer [from](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration) options to indicate that the sender email is different from the username used for authentication. It seems to me that the "from" options in my configuration.yml file is not used because I get this 550 error:

`550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender`

Using Python smtplib I have been able to send emails to validate that the credentials and configuration are working so I'm probably missing something in the configuration of the application.

Below is my configuration.yml file:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    default_options:
      from: 'email@company.com'   
  delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: ''
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      port: 1
      authentication: :login
      user_name: ''
      password: ''
      openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `From` address in outgoing mails is not configured in `configuration.yml` but in the web interface in **Administration** ➡ **Settings** ➡ **Mail notifications**.

Here, administrators can set their desired `From` address. The setting is stored in the database.